# Set number of attempts for learnr:tutorial question before moving on to the next question?

Tags: r, shiny, learnr

I am creating a homework problem with learnr:tutorial. I want to give the students 3 attempts to solve the problem before moving to the next section. I have `progressive: true` and `allow_skip: false`
But at the moment, there is unlimited try again and even with the incorrect answer, the user can continue to the next question. An example of a question is:

````
### Part (a)

```{r part-a, echo=FALSE}

question_text(
  "Input all possible rupture paths:",
    answer("ABEF", correct = TRUE),
    answer("ABCDG", correct = TRUE),
    answer("ABCDEF",correct = TRUE),
    answer("ABDEF", correct = TRUE),
  allow_retry = TRUE,
  trim = TRUE
)
```
<br><br><br><br>
---

### Part (b)

```{r part-b1, echo=FALSE}

question_text(
  "Enter the deduced length due to the bolts for the ABEF rupture path:",
    answer("1.625", correct = TRUE),
    answer("1.6", correct = TRUE),
    answer("2(13/16)",correct = TRUE),
    incorrect = "Direction from top to bottom of the plate",
  allow_retry = TRUE,
  trim = TRUE
)
```
````

**EDIT**

I came across the conditional printing of the code chunks with

`````
```{r setup, echo=FALSE}
show_text <- FALSE
````

```{r conditional_block, eval=show_text}
print("this will only print when show.text is TRUE")
```
`````

I was wondering if there is a way to set `show_text = TRUE` if the feedback from the quiz question is correct so that the next section shows up.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the docs. Maybe you can directly ask in the [github issues](https://github.com/rstudio/learnr/issues) and make a feature request if it is not implemented yet.

Comment: @starja Thank you, I will give that a try. So `allow_skip: false` does nothing right?

Comment: as far as I can see it's just a boolean option, but you can't specify the number of retries

Comment: I would also say, this just isn't implemented in the package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, the option you're looking for isn't implemented in the package.
This will perhaps be the case in up coming versions if your [request](https://github.com/rstudio/learnr/issues/430) is accepted.

In the mean time, if you're ready to rebuild the package, modification to fulfill the n attempts question is quite straight forward :

1. [download learnr-master](https://github.com/rstudio/learnr/archive/master.zip) and unpack it in a directory
2. Open learnr.Rproj under RStudio
3. Open `R/quizz.R`, find shiny module : `question_module_server_impl` and replace it by code below.
4. Build / Install & Restart
5. You can now set number of retry in allow_retry argument:

```
question_text(
  "Enter the deduced length due to the bolts for the ABEF rupture path:",
    answer("1.625", correct = TRUE),
    answer("1.6", correct = TRUE),
    answer("2(13/16)",correct = TRUE),
    incorrect = "Direction from top to bottom of the plate",
  allow_retry = 2,
  trim = TRUE
)
```

The idea is to use existing `allow_retry` argument either with boolean as before or with an integer giving the number of trials, and in this case to compare it to a reactive counter.

==================================================

Updated version of `question_module_server_impl`
Modifications highlighted in the code by `# new ===` or `# update ===` :

```
question_module_server_impl <- function(
  input, output, session,
  question
) {

  ns <- getDefaultReactiveDomain()$ns

  # new ============================
  # set counter
  val <- reactiveValues(
    numtry = 0
  )
  # ================================


  # set a seed for each user session for question methods to use
  question$seed <- random_seed()

  # only set when a submit button has been pressed
  # (or reset when try again is hit)
  # (or set when restoring)
  submitted_answer <- reactiveVal(NULL, label = "submitted_answer")

  is_correct_info <- reactive(label = "is_correct_info", {
    # question has not been submitted
    if (is.null(submitted_answer())) return(NULL)
    # find out if answer is right
    ret <- question_is_correct(question, submitted_answer())

    # new : Increment counter =======
    isolate(val$numtry <- val$numtry+1)
    # ===============================


    if (!inherits(ret, "learnr_mark_as")) {
      stop("`question_is_correct(question, input$answer)` must return a result from `correct`, `incorrect`, or `mark_as`")
    }
    ret
  })

  # should present all messages?
  is_done <- reactive(label = "is_done", {
    if (is.null(is_correct_info())) return(NULL)
    # updated ====================================================
    (!isTRUE(question$allow_retry>0)) || is_correct_info()$correct
    # ============================================================
  })


  button_type <- reactive(label = "button type", {
    if (is.null(submitted_answer())) {
      "submit"
    } else {
      # is_correct_info() should be valid
      if (is.null(is_correct_info())) {
        stop("`is_correct_info()` is `NULL` in a place it shouldn't be")
      }

      # update the submit button label
      if (is_correct_info()$correct) {
        "correct"
      } else {
        # not correct
        # updated =====================================
        if (isTRUE(val$numtry<question$allow_retry)|(question$allow_retry&is.logical(question$allow_retry))) {
          # not correct, but may try again
          "try_again"
        } else {
          # not correct and can not try again
          "incorrect"
        }
      }
    }
  })

  # disable / enable for every input$answer change
  answer_is_valid <- reactive(label = "answer_is_valid", {
    if (is.null(submitted_answer())) {
      question_is_valid(question, input$answer)
    } else {
      question_is_valid(question, submitted_answer())
    }
  })

  init_question <- function(restoreValue = NULL) {
    if (question$random_answer_order) {
      question$answers <<- shuffle(question$answers)
    }
    submitted_answer(restoreValue)
  }

  # restore past submission
  #  If no prior submission, it returns NULL
  past_submission_answer <- retrieve_question_submission_answer(session, question$label)
  # initialize like normal... nothing has been submitted
  #   or
  # initialize with the past answer
  #  this should cascade throughout the app to display correct answers and final outputs
  init_question(past_submission_answer)


  output$action_button_container <- renderUI({
    question_button_label(
      question,
      button_type(),
      answer_is_valid()
    )
  })

  output$message_container <- renderUI({
    req(!is.null(is_correct_info()), !is.null(is_done()))

    withLearnrMathJax(
      question_messages(
        question,
        messages = is_correct_info()$messages,
        is_correct = is_correct_info()$correct,
        is_done = is_done()
      )
    )
  })

  output$answer_container <- renderUI({
    if (is.null(submitted_answer())) {
      # has not submitted, show regular answers
      return(
        # if there is an existing input$answer, display it.
        # if there is no answer... init with NULL
        # Do not re-render the UI for every input$answer change
        withLearnrMathJax(
          question_ui_initialize(question, isolate(input$answer))
        )
      )
    }

    # has submitted

    if (is.null(is_done())) {
      # has not initialized
      return(NULL)
    }

    if (is_done()) {
      # if the question is 'done', display the final input ui and disable everything

      return(
        withLearnrMathJax(
          question_ui_completed(question, submitted_answer())
        )
      )
    }

    # if the question is NOT 'done', disable the current UI
    #   until it is reset with the try again button

    return(
      withLearnrMathJax(
        question_ui_try_again(question, submitted_answer())
      )
    )
  })


  observeEvent(input$action_button, {

    if (button_type() == "try_again") {
      # maintain current submission / do not randomize answer order
      # only reset the submitted answers
      # does NOT reset input$answer
      submitted_answer(NULL)

      # submit "reset" to server
      event_trigger(
        session,
        "reset_question_submission",
        data = list(
          label    = as.character(question$label),
          question = as.character(question$question)
        )
      )
      return()
    }

    submitted_answer(input$answer)

    # submit question to server
    event_trigger(
      session = session,
      event   = "question_submission",
      data    = list(
        label    = as.character(question$label),
        question = as.character(question$question),
        answer   = as.character(input$answer),
        correct  = is_correct_info()$correct
      )
    )

  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Waldi. I reinstalled the package and it works perfectly! Is there any way to further the edit to count down the number of attempts? So if an incorrect answer has been submitted the message would be "1 attempt left, try again!"

Comment: @MaralDorri, this is probably possible, but quite busy right now to look at it. Perhaps ask again on SO, if no one answers I'll have a look later on.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will create a new question in a couple of days for this as well. You have helped me tremendously by showing how to rebuild packages!